# php convert string with new lines into array?

Tags: php

I am getting data from an API and the resulting string is

```
[RESPONSE]
PROPERTY[STATUS][0]=ACTIVE
PROPERTY[REGISTRATIONEXPIRATIONDATE][0]=2012-04-04 19:48:48
DESCRIPTION=Command completed successfully
QUEUETIME=0
CODE=200
RUNTIME=0.352

QUEUETIME=0
RUNTIME=0.8

EOF
```

I am trying to convert this into an array like

```
Array(
['PROPERTY[STATUS][0]'] => ACTIVE,
['CODE'] => 200,
...
);
```

So I am trying to explode it using the resulting file_get_content function with an explode like

```
$output = explode('=',file_get_contents($url));
```

But the problem is the returning values are not always returned in the same order, so I need to have it like `$array['CODE'] = 200`, and `$array['RUNTIME'] = 0.352` however there does not seem to be any kind of new line characters? I tried `\r\n, \n, <br>, \r\n\r\n` in the explode function to no avail. But there is new lines in both notepad and the browser.

So my question is there some way to determine if a string is on a new line or determine what the character forcing the new line is? If not is there some other way I could read this into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out what the breaking character is, you could do this (if `$data` contatins the string example you've posted):

```
echo ord($data[strlen('[RESPONSE]')]) . PHP_EOL;
echo ord($data[strlen('[RESPONSE]')+1]);          // if there's a second char
```

Then take a look in the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to see what it is.

*EDIT*: Then you could explode the data using that newly found character:

```
explode(ord($ascii_value), $data);
```

---

Btw, does `file()` return a correct array?

Comment: @Steven, when you have it's ASCII value, you can explode like this: `explode(ord($ascii_value), $data);`.

Comment: +1 Nice approach. But he's not telling us what character it was(?). I demand to be told!!! :}

Comment: LF, that's what I suggested in my answer, who the hell down-voted it?

Answer (score 1):

Explode on `"\n"` with double quotes so PHP understands this is a line feed and not a backslashed `n` ;-) then explode each item on `=`

Comment: "however there does not seem to be any kind of new line characters? I tried \r\n, \n, <br>, \r\n\r\n in the explode function to no avail. But there is new lines in both notepad and the browser." I tried that and it doesn't seem to be exploding. See http://www.lii.in/drop_catch.php for example

Comment: Did you explode on `'\n'` or `"\n"`? The first one will fail

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `parse_ini_file()` or `parse_ini_string()`?

It should do everything you need (build an array) in one easy step.

Comment: @mario, interesting that PHP only supports one set of brackets. That's a silly restriction that I was unaware of.

Comment: I'm lookin at this from the upside: At least it supports one level of array syntax. Might not suffice in this case, but nice function to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
preg_split("/$/m", $str)
```

or

```
preg_split("/$\n?/m", $str)
```

for the split

Answer (score 0):

The lazy solution would be:

```
$response = strtr($response, "\r", "\n");
preg_match_all('#^(.+)=(.+)\s*$#m', $response, $parts);
$parts = array_combine($parts[1], $parts[2]);
```

Gives you:

```
Array (
 [PROPERTY[STATUS][0]] => ACTIVE
 [PROPERTY[REGISTRATIONEXPIRATIONDATE][0]] => 2012-04-04 19:48:48
 [DESCRIPTION] => Command completed successfully
 [QUEUETIME] => 0
 [CODE] => 200
 [RUNTIME] => 0.8
```